# why I think wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
Let $u_1, u_2, ...,u_k$ be vectors in $R^n$, and P a square matrix of order n. Show that if $Pu_1, Pu_2, ...,Pu_k$ are linearly independent, then $u_1, u_2, ..., u_k$ are independent.

What I did was that I tried to induct

$c_1Pu_1+c_2Pu_2+...+c_kPu_k=0$ where $c_1=c_2=...=c_k=0$

to

$c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...+c_ku_k=0$ where $c_1=c_2=...=c_k=0$

and I got stuck.

However, my teacher gave the answer in the opposite direction. 
He inducted from

Let $c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...+c_ku_k=0$

Then pre-multiply matrix P to both sides of the equation.

$P(c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...+c_ku_k)=P0$

then

$c_1Pu_1+c_2Pu_2+...+c_kPu_k=0$

because $Pu_1, Pu_2, ...,Pu_k$ are linearly independent, so $c_1=c_2=...=c_k=0$

It worked! It was an amazing proof. But I was kind of wondering why two opposite thinking would result in so different results. I know I thought in the wrong direction. But I still didn't get the point so that I will not do wrong similarly. Can anyone provide some analysis?

Comment: Suppose you want to make mashed potatoes. You need potatoes, boil them, and then mash them. If you begin with peanuts, fry them and then grind them, you don't get mashed potatoes.

Comment: You want to prove $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ are l.i. What is the definition of l.i.? We must begin by searching for what that definition is asking. The definition says that if you find a linear combination of them $c_1u_1+\ldots+c_ku_k$ that is equal to zero, then the coefficients $c_1,\ldots,c_k$ must have been equal to zero.

Comment: The definition is an implication. So, from assuming that $c_1u_1+\ldots+c_ku_k=0$ we must, using the information given, get to $c_1=\ldots=c_k=0$.

Comment: The question asks to show that "$Pu_1, \dots, Pu_k$ independent $\implies u_1, \dots, u_k$ independent". This is equivalent to "$u_1, \dots, u_k\;\text{independent} \implies Pu_1, \dots, Pu_k \;\text{independent}$". That statement is easy to prove by assuming a linear relation between the $u_i$ and finding one between the $Pu_i$.

Comment: "$u_1,\ldots,u_k$ independent $\Rightarrow Pu_1,\ldots, Pu_k$ independent" is not true. It should be "$u_1,\ldots,u_k$ dependent $\Rightarrow Pu_1,\ldots, Pu_k$ dependent".

Answer (score 3):

It's a very common mistake starting a proof of linear independence by saying

$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_kv_k=0\quad\text{where}\quad
c_1=c_2=\dots=c_k=0.$$

This is obvious and so it is *never* useful in this kind of proofs. What you want to prove is very different, namely that

> the only case where $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_kv_k=0$ is when $c_1=c_2=\dots=c_k=0$

So, when you're given a statement such as

> Prove that the vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$ are linearly independent if (C)

where (C) stands for any particular condition in your problem, you should do according to the following pattern:

> Suppose $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_kv_k=0$. Then …reasoning…, so we conclude that $c_1=c_2=\dots=c_k=0$. Therefore we have proved the vectors are linearly independent.

---

In your particular case you can say

- Suppose $c_1u_1+c_2u_2+\dots+c_ku_k=0$
- Then $P(c_1u_1+c_2u_2+\dots+c_ku_k)=P0$
- Therefore $c_1Pu_1+c_2Pu_2+\dots+c_kPu_k=0$
- Since $Pu_1,Pu_2,\dots,P_uk$ are, by hypothesis, linearly independent, we conclude that $c_1=c_2=\dots=c_k=0$

Comment: I am rather confused now. I think the reason why I am confused now may be that I cann't correctly interpret the proof logic of this question. Is the definition of linear independent a if(conditional) statement? such as: if c1v1+c2v2+⋯+ckvk=0 and c1=c2=⋯=ck=0 then v1,v2,…,vk are linearly independent. please judge my understanding.

Comment: @user2262504 It's a wrong understanding: $0v_1+0v_2+\dots+0v_k=0$ is surely true for any set of vectors. "If $c_1v_1+\dots+c_kvk$ *implies* $c_1=\dots=c_k=0$, then $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are linearly independent. Connecting two statements with "implies" or "and" gives very different results.

Comment: But I still don't know the "hypothesis" and "conclusion" of this implication. Is the hypothesis: 0v1+0v2+⋯+0vk=0 conclusion:c1=⋯=ck=0 and v1,…,vk are linearly independent? Because if a conditional statement is true, conclusion can be gotten if the hypothesis is satisfied. Am I understanding right?

Comment: @user2262504 Sorry, no, you're still understanding wrong. The condition for linear independence is the whole implication: "$c_1v_1+\dots+c_kv_k=0$ implies $c_1=\dots=c_k=0$".

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I think I understand your analysis now. It really help a lot for clear my understanding of the definition of linear independent. I will try to understand every mathematics definition and theorem in a logic way. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you did not respect the correct order for proof.
What do you want to prove ?
That $u_1,u_2, \ldots ,u_n$ are independent.

So your proof MUST go like this :

(1) Suppose $c_1u_1+c_2u_2+ \ldots +c_ku_k=0$.

(2) Blah Blah Blah

(3) Therefore $c_1=c_2=c_3=\ldots =c_k=0$.

It seems you were confused and put item 1 in place 3.

Comment: Thank you for your clear analysis. By the way, does every question which needs to be proved have the order of proof? Because I don't notice the concept of order of proof before.

Comment: @user2262504 As noted in ABC’s comments, the order of proof depends on the definition. Here the definition is an implication “from A to B”. So the proof must follow this order, from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know elementary logic. Your problem: $(u_i)_i$ are given.
(H): if $\sum_ic_iPu_i=0$, then $(c_i)_i=(0)_i$.
(C): if $\sum_id_iu_i=0$, then $(d_i)_i=(0)_i$. Show that (H) implies (C).

Solution: 1. you rush on (C) and not to (H), otherwise you are dead !

1. Now your hypothesis is: (H) and  $\sum_id_iu_i=0$ (hypothesis of (C)).
2. $P(\sum_id_iu_i)=0=\sum_id_iP(u_i)$ and you apply (H) for $c_i=d_i$.

Notes: 1. Here we take $(c_i)=(d_i)$ but it is not true in general. Take always two different notations for these coefficients. 2. That is above is the standard method and if you don't understand that, you are dead again!